# Anyone able to get directory listing feature work in Android

Tags: google-drive-api

It seems that, recent released Google Drive SDK supports directory listing.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

I try to integrate it into my Android app.

```
package com.jstock.cloud;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleKeyInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android2.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.jstock.gui.Utils;

public class CloudFile {
    public final java.io.File file;
    public final long checksum;
    public final long date;
    public final int version;
    private CloudFile(java.io.File file, long checksum, long date, int version) {
        this.file = file;
        this.checksum = checksum;
        this.date = date;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public static CloudFile newInstance(java.io.File file, long checksum, long date, int version) {
        return new CloudFile(file, checksum, date, version);
    }

    public static CloudFile loadFromGoogleDrive(String authToken) {
        final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
        credential.setAccessToken(authToken);
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(Utils.getApplicationName())
            .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new GoogleKeyInitializer(ClientCredentials.KEY))
            .build();

        List<File> files = retrieveAllFiles(service);
        Log.i("CHEOK", "size is " + files.size());
        for (File file : files) {
            Log.i(TAG, "title = " + file.getTitle());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of File resources.
     *
     * @param service Drive API service instance.
     * @return List of File resources.
     */
    private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = null;
        try {
            request = service.files().list();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            return result;
        }

        do {
            try {
                FileList files = request.execute();

                result.addAll(files.getItems());
                request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);
                request.setPageToken(null);
            }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

        Log.i("CHEOK", "yup!");
        return result;
    } 

    private static final String TAG = "CloudFile";
}
```

I always get 0 file returned from server, and there isn't any exception being thrown. Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to request access to the full Drive scope to list all files: https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes#requesting_full_drive_scope_for_an_app

If you use the default (and recommended) scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, you will only be able to see files created or opened by the app.